# Resize UI elements with mouse UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I have `Pinch to zoom` scaling but I need also do it with mouse. How I can implement it because I can drag my images too.

This is my code for scaling by fingers

```
  private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var ct = (CompositeTransform)image.RenderTransform;
      ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
      ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a final result, you need release mouse button after finished resize

```
private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = sender as Border;  
            if (mousePos.X> pos.X|| mousePos.Y > pos.Y)
            {
                ct.ScaleX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                ct.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            }
            if (mousePos.X < pos.X || mousePos.Y < pos.Y)
            {
                ct.ScaleX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                ct.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            }
    }
  private void ImageBorder_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pos = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
    }

    private void ImageBorder_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pos = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have Pinch to zoom scaling but I need also do it with mouse.

You can use [UIElement.PointerWheelChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerwheelchanged.aspx) event to change the scale:

Code-Behind:

```
private void Image_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int delta=e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
    var ct = (CompositeTransform)img.RenderTransform;
    ct.ScaleX += delta / 120;//you can set 120 to other value to change the sensitivity
    ct.ScaleY += delta / 120;
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Canvas Width="800" Height="800">
    <Image Name="img" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/profiler.jpeg" PointerWheelChanged="Image_PointerWheelChanged"></Image>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I saw this variant but I want do it with mouse like when you resize window

Comment: What do you mean by "do it with mouse like when you resize window"?

Comment: I mean, tap on border of `Image` you can drag and resize it